# how can I fine-tune this basic math expression (which use fp) to match these input/outputs?

Tags: c++, floating-point, fine-tuning

here's my code:

```
int counter = 0;
float h = 1.0f;
float phase = 0.0f;
const float hrate = 1.0f / (100.0f * (h * h) + 0.02f);
while (!(phase > 100.0f))
{
    phase += hrate;
    counter++;
}
std::cout << counter << std::endl;
```

i need to fine-tune it to output these `counter`s, for each `h` (using my actual pc/compilator):

```
  h   counter
0.0   3      
0.2   403    
0.4   1602   
0.5   2502   
0.6   3602   
0.8   6402   
1.0   10002
```

instead, it gives to me this:

```
  h   counter
0.0   3
0.2   402     << different
0.4   1602
0.5   2502
0.6   3602
0.8   6403    << different
1.0   10004   << different
```

Comment: "Fine tuning" this code will result in brittle (not robust) code with respect to the target objective. But if one absolutely wanted to go down that path, the following works for me with strictest floating-point setting on the Intel compiler: ` double phase = 0.0; const double hrate = 1.0 / (99.996 * h * h + 0.0202);`

Comment: @njuffa magic! how did you end up with those results? "brute force" values? :O

Comment: Educated guesses based on the "rounding" behavior.

Comment: @njuffa i see. well, the formula is weird. Dunno someone will write this kind of math. Any other math path that can reach the same result in your opinion?

Comment: The question is missing context. Are you trying to replicate a computation from a historical system maybe that used non-IEEE floating-point arithmetic (maybe with truncation instead rounding for basic arithmetic) or fixed-point arithmetic? Or maybe it used an algorithm to translate between `h` and `counter` that is quite different from the one used in this code?

Comment: I posted an answer below, however it would be helpful to point out which compilers are you comparing exactly, and which environment.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you need to rely on these kind of behavior, you want to `static_assert` for `is_iec559`. This *should* ensure that all the floating point computation produce deterministic results.

You also want to make sure you are not using `-ffast-math` or similar switches. I believe that well behaved compiler should not report `iec559` when `-ffast-math` is enabled, but that's not currently the case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cfenv>

static_assert(std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559, "");

void test_it(float h)
{
    int counter = 0;
    float phase = 0.0f;
    const float hrate = 1.0f / (100.0f * (h * h) + 0.02f);
    while (!(phase > 100.0f))
    {
        phase += hrate;
        counter++;
    }
    std::cout << counter << std::endl;
}
```

Once we got that out the way, we want to pay attention to the floating point [rounding mode](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round). In theory this should default to `FE_TONEAREST`, but if you have a large code base there is no guarantee that other code is messing with it (rounding mode, and all the floating point environment, is a thread-local state).

```
int main()
{
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
    std::fesetround(FE_TONEAREST);
    test_it(0.2f); // 402
    test_it(0.8f); // 6403
    test_it(1.0f); // 10004

    std::fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
    test_it(0.2f); // 403
    test_it(0.6f); // 6403
    test_it(1.0f); // 10005

    std::fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
    test_it(0.2f); // 402
    test_it(0.6f); // 6402
    test_it(1.0f); // 10001
}
```

I have not run the math myself, but both `gcc` and `clang` agree with these results.

Finally, be aware that constant expressions are always evaluated with FE_TONEAREST.
Your original code "hardcodes" the value of `h`. It is possible that this is causing `hrate` to be constant-evaluted (with the FE_TONEAREST), which might then affect the result.